# External USB NTFS drive not recognized in macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, disk-utility, usb, high-sierra, ntfs

My external USB drive, formatted as NTFS, is no longer being recognized in High Sierra.

As soon as I plug it in I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried running First Aid in Disk Utility but it is greyed out.

[image]

I then tried to verify the disk in Terminal and this is what it spit out:

[image]

When I type in diskutil repairvolume /Volumes/SSD/ it spits out the same error and then un-mounts the drive.

Is my drive corrupted beyond repair? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by performing a chkdsk /f in Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) And thanks for coming back to share how you resolved it. Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/315231/edit) your answer to provide some more details? In particular explaining *how* you perform a `chkdsk /f` in Windows will probably help a lot of users who wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: It should also be noted that anyone can download a free Windows VM from Microsoft (via the http://modern.ie project) and then run it from a Mac or Linux computer via VirtualBox.